# Ambiguous error messages within Trivial Drive

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am attempting to get google's example (in-app purchasing [version 3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)) test app "TrivialDrive" to work, but have the following problem:

I click the "buy gas" button, this brings up the following screen:

[image]

There are two possible interpretations of this message:

1. The item is unavailable THEREFORE this user can not get it.
2. The user is somehow not eligible to purchase this item THEREFORE the item is unavailable.

So which is it? And why might I be getting this error anyway?

By the way the app has been uploaded to my developer account yesterday, so I have far exceeded the 2-3 hour wait Google recommends for the data to be in the system.

Also I have "Play Store" installed on the device.

Just for good measure here is a screen grab from my developer account:

[image]

I am running the app from a device registered with a gmail address which is on my developer's "Test Accounts" list.

**EDIT:** I just tested another app of mine which used the old-style (Version 2) billing system and it reported "Please first complete your account by adding a payment method". So it would seem that the lack of payment method was the ultimate cause - but I wouldn't want potential customers to be presented with such a useless and misleading error message. I did a search for "item unavailable" in the MainActivity.java and the strings.xml and found nothing, so am at a loss as to haw to avoid this scenario.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you registered your test device, is the test account the only account registered on it? Particularly, it should be the first account registered on it. A hard reset is the way to go if it's not.

Comment: The answer is yes. I didn't even know it was possible to have more than one account active on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have yet to publish the overarching app that the in-app product is supposed to stem from.  As a result, Google does not allow you to pay for an in-app product if the application itself has yet to be published.  Once you release the application and publish it, you should be able to access the in-app product's sales page.

> An in-app product will appear UNPUBLISHED until the owning application is published.

Even if you were to publish your in-app product, nobody can buy it until your actual application is.

Comment: Confusingly there are two meanings for "published" in google play. One for the individual purchasable items and, separately, one for the app as a whole. The individual items ARE published, but the app is not. According to google, I should be able to make test purchases in this state. If this were not true then it would be impossible for anyone to debug their purchasing systems before publication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a test account? The test account should not be the your google play dev account. 
[Explained here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Comment: I have set up a test account, and the test account is not a developer account.